# When I run this code only data of two nodes and the data of new node is shown but data third and fourth node is not shown

Tags: java, data-structures

In this code only data of first second and new node is shown but I want the data of all the nodes.

```
package linkedlispack;

 public class InsertLast {
  Node head;
  static class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int d){
        data=d;
        next=null;

    }
   }
    public void printlist()
    {
    Node n = head;
    while(n!=null){
        System.out.println(n.data+"");
        n=n.next;
    }
      }
     public void push(int new_data){
      Node new_node=new Node(new_data);
       if(head==null){
        head=new Node(new_data);
        return;
       }

    new_node.next=null;

    Node last=head;
    while(last!=null){
        last=last.next;

        last.next=new_node;
        return;
    }
```

upto last node is created

```
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       InsertLast list=new InsertLast();
       list.head=new Node(4);
       Node second=new Node(10);
```

here third and fourth node

```
       Node third=new Node(12);
       Node fourth=new Node(20);


        list.head.next=second;

        second.next=third;
        third.next=fourth;


        list.push(15);
        list.printlist();

}

 }
```

output shown 4 10 15 .But I want output 4 10 12 20 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in that you are assigning the next element to Nodes created outside the list. You have to push the elements. If you create them outside instead of pushing them you have to point them using the object list. You did it here:
`list.head.next=second;`

If you want to keep linking elements to the list use the push method or you have to do it manually by using a lot of next's like this:`list.head.next.next.next=new Node(element)` but as previously said the push method is the recommendation here.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use debugger and step through your code?

Your `push`is wrong. By calling `list.push(15)` you are attaching new node to second node and dropping third and fourth nodes.